# How to create a wrapper component where both the inner and outer components are passed in as props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make a wrapped element so I can wrap something with a provided-via-passed-props React context provider.

EDIT: from You can see my attempt here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-lxdb6l?file=src%2FApp.tsx

The reason I am doing this as a wrapped component is because the number of 'parent' components that will be passed will be an array of components (ie: a bunch of React context providers) so I can't just hard code it directly.

```
const WrappedComponent: React.JSX.ElementType = (OutterComponent: React.JSX.ElementType, InnerComponent: React.JSX.ElementType) => {
        return <OutterComponent>{InnerComponent}</OutterComponent>
    }
```

If I change to `React.JSX.ElementType`, the TypeScript errors go away:

```
const WrappedComponent: React.JSX.ElementType = (OutterComponent: React.JSX.ElementType, InnerComponent: React.JSX.ElementType) => {
        return <OutterComponent>{InnerComponent}</OutterComponent>
    }
```

However, I still can't use the component:

```
return <WrappedComponent
    OutterComponent={<Tooltip title={'just testing purposes'} >{'blah'}</Tooltip>}
    InnerComponent={<Button>Button text</Button>}
/>
```

Provides a whole host of errors:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for build-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got : object
```

In the end, what I want to do is be able to optionally pass a context to this component and wrap the 'innerComponent'. The goal is to create a generic library that will recieve a context as a prop and wrap itself with the provider so all the sub-elements in the library (also passed as props) will be able to utilize the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should point out you can simply do:

```
import { FC, PropsWithChildren } from 'react';

const OuterComponent: FC<PropsWithChildren> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
        <Tooltip title={'just testing purposes'}>
          {'blah'}
          <br />
          {children}
        </Tooltip>
  );
};

const InnerComponent = <Button>Button text</Button>;

return (
      <OuterComponent>InnerComponent</OuterComponent>
);
```

But I've fixed your code below in case there's some reason you need this pattern.

---

Fixing the type definitions of `WrappedComponent`:

```
import { FC, PropsWithChildren, ReactNode } from 'react';

type WrappedComponentProps = {
  OuterComponent: FC<PropsWithChildren>;
  InnerComponent: ReactNode;
};
const WrappedComponent: FC<WrappedComponentProps> = ({
  OuterComponent,
  InnerComponent,
}) => {
  return <OuterComponent>{InnerComponent}</OuterComponent>;
};
```

You would use it like this:

```
return (
    <WrappedComponent
      OuterComponent={({ children }) => (
        <Tooltip title={'just testing purposes'}>
          {'blah'}
          <br />
          {children}
        </Tooltip>
      )}
      InnerComponent={<Button>Button text</Button>}
    />
  );
```

If you're not aware, whatever appears between two JSX component tags is simply passed to the `children` property of the parent `props`.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-n7j9t8?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Comment: I'm not actually trying to wrap with a Tooltip.  I'm trying to wrap with a passed-as-a-prop React context provider.  The goal is to create a generic library that will recieve a context as a prop and wrap itself with the provider so all the sub-elements in the library (also passed as props) will be able to utilize the context.

Comment: Like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-lxdb6l?file=src%2FApp.tsx